# LDAP - search filter with multiple groups

Tags: php, ldap

I have the following filter and want to extend it to include another cn group:

```
$filter ="(&(cn=PATH*)(cn=*2013*))";
```

So that it includes `&(cn=PATH*)(cn=*2013*)` AND  `&(cn=MICR*)(cn=*2013*)`

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure the syntax is the following:

```
(&(&(cn=PATH*)(cn=*2013*))(&(cn=MICR*)(cn=*2013*)))
```

This format would be more useful with an OR statement, meaning either both the first, or both the second as such:

```
(|(&(cn=PATH*)(cn=*2013*))(&(cn=MICR*)(cn=*2013*)))
```

Alternately if you simply want all four matched:

```
(&(cn=PATH*)(cn=*2013*)(cn=MICR*)(cn=*2013*))
```

Comment: Thanks again Fluffeh!  (|(&(cn=PATH*)(cn=*2013*))(&(cn=MICR*)(cn=*2013*))) works for me.